# Nodejs Follow System Not Working Properly

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a **follow system**

```
app.get('/user/:id', function(req, res){
User.findById(req.user
).exec(function(err, user){

User.findById(req.params.id, function(err, kullanici){
User.findById(user, {follower:kullanici._id}, function(err, follow){
if(follow== ""+kullanici._id+""){
console.log("sdasdsad")
}else{
console.log("no")
}
...
```

**kullanici**= user in profile

**user**= current user

**follow** =the users who follows the kullanici

When current user is one of the takip then I will console log sdasdsad but else I will console.log no.

But it always returns as no in my console.

Why it is not working?

And also it is my user.js part:

```
follower:[{
type: ObjectId,
}]
```

When I do console.log(follow)

```
{ follower:
   [ 5edfe8f3bfc9d677005d55ca,
     5edfe92fbfc9d677005d55cc,
     5ee2326cc7351c5bb0b75f1a ],
  _id: 5eef29617e748990845fd7b1 }
```

When I do console.log(kullanici._id)

```
5edfe92fbfc9d677005d55cc,
```