# Javascript Equalize Element From Array

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays

Guys I want to get an element from array. Here:

**Follower:**

```
{ follower:
   [ 5edfe8f3bfc9d677005d55ca,
     5edfe92fbfc9d677005d55cc,
     5ee2326cc7351c5bb0b75f1a ],
```

**user id:**

```
5edfe92fbfc9d677005d55cc
```

**The process:**

```
if(follower == user){
          console.log("sdasdsad")
        }else{
          console.log("no")
        }
```

But when I do it it always returns as no.
Also this is the codes of===> [Nodejs Follow System Not Working Properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62626123/nodejs-follow-system-not-working-properly)

It is a nodejs project. So please look at the above link.

When I do

```
if(follower.includes(user)){
```

It gives the error of:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'includes' of null

And when I try to change some I get this error:

> TypeError: takip.includes is not a function

Guys so thats why I say please look at the above code.

So how to equalize them?

Comment: `follower` is not a variable but a property. What is `user`? You should at least post the code with which we can reproduce the problem.

Comment: Also I guess an array probably won't be equal to a string. Maybe you want [`Array.prototype.includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)?

Comment: Try `obj.follower.indexOf(user) > -1`

Comment: Guys it is a nodejs project, I eddited the question and added a link Could you please look at it again?

Comment: `follower.includes(user)` won't work for sure, because it is a property of another object. So you can't access it directly. You need to get the actual object, which is in your other question you said it is `follow` and access the `follower` property within it. So the result will be `follow.follower.includes(user)`.

Comment: Thanks @SMAKSS it worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As other peoples said earlier the **follower itself is a property which its value is an array itself**, so if you want to check whether an item exists within it or not you can check it with [`includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes), if it exists it will return true otherwise it will return false.

```js
const follow = {
  follower: ["5edfe8f3bfc9d677005d55ca",
    "5edfe92fbfc9d677005d55cc",
    "5ee2326cc7351c5bb0b75f1a"
  ]
}

const user = "5edfe92fbfc9d677005d55cc";

if (follow.follower.includes(user)) {
  console.log("sdasdsad")
} else {
  console.log("no")
}
```

But if you looking to find the exact position of the item within that array you can find it with [`indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf). If the item does not exist within the array it will return `-1`, otherwise, it will return the index of that item within the array.

```js
const follow = {
  follower: ["5edfe8f3bfc9d677005d55ca",
    "5edfe92fbfc9d677005d55cc",
    "5ee2326cc7351c5bb0b75f1a"
  ]
}

const user = "5edfe92fbfc9d677005d55cc";

console.log(follow.follower.indexOf(user));
```

Comment: Yes but it is a nodejs project, I eddited the question and added a link  Could you please look at it again?

Comment: @Ö.ALPERENGÜL Well it makes no difference if it is a Node JS or regular JS project, `indexOf` and `includes` will work perfectly in any JS apps.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to compare a string to an array so it will never pass the if statement.

If you change your if to be `if ( follower.includes(user)) {` then it will search the array for the string.

```js
var follower = [ 
  '5edfe8f3bfc9d677005d55ca',
  '5edfe92fbfc9d677005d55cc',
  '5ee2326cc7351c5bb0b75f1a' 
]

var user = '5edfe92fbfc9d677005d55cc'
// This will always fail as follower is an array not a string
if (follower.includes(user)){
  console.log("sdasdsad")
} else {
  console.log("no")
}
```

References

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes

Comment: Yes but it is a nodejs project, I eddited the question and added a link and when I do includes() it says:TypeError: follower.includes is not a function. Could you please look at it again?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array.protorype.some()` to check if `user` exists in the `follower` array.

```js
const obj = { 
  follower: [ 
    "5edfe8f3bfc9d677005d55ca",
    "5edfe92fbfc9d677005d55cc",
    "5ee2326cc7351c5bb0b75f1a"
  ]
}
     
const user = "5edfe92fbfc9d677005d55cc";

if(obj.follower.some(item => item === user)) {
    console.log("found")
} else{
    console.log("no")
}
```

You can also get the item with `Array.protorype.find()` with the same way as above, just assign it to a variable

[Array.prototype.some](http://%5Benter%20link%20description%20here%5D%5B1%5D)

[Array.prototype.find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

Comment: Actually Yes but it is a nodejs project, I eddited the question and added a link Could you please look at it again?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like **follower** is a property. You can use this solution:

```
objectName.follower.forEach(item =>
    if (item == user) console.log(`${item} is the answer`);
);
```

This way, javascript will go through all of the elements in the array and print it out if it is matching with your **user** variable.

You can also use for loop or while loop for the same process, however, since you're using an array, forEach will be much more useful.

If this was not your question and I misunderstood your question, let me know, I'll see if I can help.

Comment: Eyvallah abi ama hallettim

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps

```js
var obj = { 
    follower: [ '5edfe8f3bfc9d677005d55ca',
     '5edfe92fbfc9d677005d55cc',
     '5ee2326cc7351c5bb0b75f1a'
     ]
};

var userId = '5edfe92fbfc9d677005d55cc';

function searchUser(object, user){
    if(obj.follower.includes(user)){
        return object.follower.filter(x => x == user);
    } else {
        return 'no';
    }
};

console.log(searchUser(obj, userId));
```